# Printer installation fails with "Unable to install printer - Some driver files are missing or incorrect"

Tags: windows, printing, driver

Attempting to install [my custom printer driver](https://github.com/TazeTSchnitzel/LetterMaster-Unidrv) that I'm working on (a Unidrv minidriver-based one) fails with this error (Windows 8.1 Pro x64):

[image: Unable to install printer - Some driver files are missing or incorrect]

The LetterMaster.gpd file can be found here: https://github.com/TazeTSchnitzel/LetterMaster-Unidrv/blob/f9bcd4756bd095629d6a49115af17ce3bb16169c/LetterMaster.gpd (though I doubt it is the problem)

The INF file is known to be fine.

By "install" I mean going to Add printer -> blah -> Have Disk -> choosing the INF file -> clicking Next -> filling in the name of the printer -> Next. It'll then show UAC prompt, seem to go alright for a bit, but then the error above shows up.

**EDIT:** After using `gpdcheck` I was able to fix some syntactic errors in the `LetterMaster.gpd` file which I didn't know existed. Now I have a new error:

[image: Unable to install printer. Cannot complete this function.]

The LetterMaster.gpd content is now this: https://github.com/TazeTSchnitzel/LetterMaster-Unidrv/blob/10c4eed1c0b1592dbdd00466bc7a31a259223dbe/LetterMaster.gpd

Comment: It was a few years ago that I "programmed" this damnable Unidrv for a specialized "printer" The printer actually produced embossed cards similar to a credit card.

Comment: The API for the printer was created by brain damaged hamsters and Microsoft's documentation and API for Unidrv I am convinced was written by chimps that were more interested in eating their own feces than producing anything useful. I did finally get my custom driver to work with the embossing machine and I wish I still had the source code so I could share the secret incantation I literally stumbled upon. Best of luck anyway.

Comment: In the end I just wrote my own print processor in Haskell. It's just a daisy-wheel printer, so all you really need is justification, bold and underline.